# $g$ is a real function on $\mathbb{R^1}$ with bounded $g'(x)$. Define $f(x) = x + \epsilon g(x)$. Prove that $f$ is 1-to-1 if $\epsilon$ small enough

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Suppose $g$ is a real function on $\mathbb{R^1}$ with bounded derivative (say $|g'| \leq M$). Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and Define $f(x) = x + \epsilon g(x)$. Prove that $f$ is one-to-one is $\epsilon$ small enough

---

**My Proof**

Since we have $|g'(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R^1}$, $g$ contains no discontinuities of the first or second kind (i.e. $g(x) \not \to \infty$ for any $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$)

Thus $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^1}$, there exists a $N$ such that $g(x) \leq N$

Therefore if we take $\epsilon > 0$ small enough $\epsilon g(x) \to 0$ and $f(x) = x$ which is a one-to-one function as desired $ \ \square$

---

Is my proof correct, and logically/rigorously sound?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some underlying ideas that you've failed to capture in your writing, but this looks completely wrong in basically every way. I apologize for being blunt, but I can't think of any softer way of putting it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my proof correct, and logically/rigorously sound?

no… it's a bit "handwaving".
To be rigorously consider $f'$ and show $f' > 0$ für $\varepsilon$ small enough, so f is strictly monotone and so one-to-one

Comment: Just out of curiosity is it *handwaving* in the sense that it's not a proof at all, or *handwaving* in the sense that it's sketchy/incomplete? I'm just looking to see where I can improve my rigor, and a benchmark would be nice

Comment: It's incomplete… e.g. you claim

Comment: >  if we take $ϵ>0$ small enough $ϵg(x)→0$
for a fixed $x\in R$ you are right, but not for all
> and $f(x)=x$
it's true that for a small $\varepsilon$ f increases almost like the identity but it's never equal to it… so tbh this is wrong